# Disabled tap to click still works for some checkboxes?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, 15.04, touchpad, gedit

I have disabled tap-to-click in the system settings, and it is disabled in most cases, however it still registers in some places, e.g. for checkboxes in system settings and the sudo password dialog. Is there some way to turn it off completely?

EDIT:
Also in nautilus and gedit in 15.04. This makes gedit unusable, since palm detection does not work on this touchpad.